# Getting style information (css) of a node after parsing an html page in Java

Tags: java, css, parsing, dom, css-parsing

I'm developing a project who analyzes web pages. I use an Java library for HTML parsing, and it returns an `org.w3c.dom` document.

Given a tag node in my `dom` document, I'd like to know all the CSS info connected to that node (including override/inheritance).

How I can do this? Searching on Google, I found some CSS parsers that generate an `org.w3c.dom` document, but how should I mix them?

Comment: This might be what you're looking for:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/754607/can-jquery-get-all-css-styles-associated-with-an-element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[jStyleParser](http://cssbox.sourceforge.net/jstyleparser/) provides exactly this functionality. It parses all the referenced style sheets and maps them to the DOM tree nodes. More options are offered for a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513587/looking-for-a-css-parser-in-java).