# HTML special parsers

Tags: html, css, parsing

I have a task that requires parsing HTML pages and get all the tags with their attribute. Parsing an HTML page is not a big issue and I know many open source projects that can do the job. However, if an HTML tag use a CSS class or inherit attributes from a div tag that uses a CSS class then I will also need to get all the attributes from the CSS that the tag uses.

Comment: a similar question which might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13614392/how-to-parse-html-and-get-css-styles and another one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11473410/getting-style-information-css-of-a-node-after-parsing-an-html-page-in-java