# parsing html and getting applied element style

Tags: java, html, css

I want to use a Java library to parse HTML.

I also want to be able to get the applied css style for the text element. Currently I only want to know the font style and size.

The style could be applied directly or from a css file. I realize it can also be applied using JavaScript but I don't need that support as of now.

Currently I am looking at [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) but I don't see such support. Are there any other libraries that I can use? It would be preferable if I don't have to use a full browser engine to get this functionality.

Answer (score 3):

The [CSSParser](http://cssparser.sourceforge.net/) at least allows to parse a CSS document and iterate the different style rules. In the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1857265/658718) to the question [Looking for a CSS Parser in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513587/looking-for-a-css-parser-in-java) you will find an example usage.

CSSParser is a Java implementation of W3C's [SAC: The Simple API for CSS](http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/SAC/)

> SAC 1.0 is a standard interface for CSS parser and supposed to work
>   with CSS1, CSS2, CSS3 (currently under development) and other CSS
>   derived languages.

But this would force you to roll your own implementation between JSoup and CSSParser. The only project which implements a `getComputedStyle` method in Java is the [Lobo Java Browser](http://lobobrowser.org/java-browser.jsp). Unfortunately discontinued since 2009, but I don't think that this yields a problem.

At least they offer this method:

[`public org.lobobrowser.html.style.AbstractCSS2Properties getComputedStyle(java.lang.String pseudoElement`)](http://lobobrowser.org/cobra-api/org/lobobrowser/html/domimpl/HTMLElementImpl.html#getComputedStyle%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: Thanks. I think that should work. The example usage on that link seems to only load the CSS and parse, instead of applying it to an HTML document. Anyway, I'll have a closer look and update this page.

Comment: @arahant You are right, CSSParser cannot apply this on a HTML DOM. The only project that I am aware of is Lobo Java Browser. They have implemented a Java equivalent of the [JavaScript method `getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.getComputedStyle?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%3Awindow.getComputedStyle). See my edited answers for additional links.