# How to parse HTML and get CSS styles

Tags: java, parsing, html-parsing, css-parsing

I need to parse HTML and find corresponding CSS styles. I can parse HTML and CSS separataly, but I can't combine them. For example, I have an XHTML page like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="abc">Hello World</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have to search for "hello world" and find its class name, and after that I need to find its style from an external CSS file. Answers using Java, JavaScript, and PHP are all okay.

Comment: you could loop over all elements and check styles.  This sounds like a very difficult task, since styles can overlap.  Can you elaborate on your goal?  Do you just need styles applied to text?

Answer (score 3):

Use [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) library in java which is a HTML Parser. You can see for example [here](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/)

For example you can do something like this:

```
String html="<<your html content>>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Element ele=doc.getElementsContainingOwnText("Hello World").first.clone(); //get tag containing Hello world
HashSet<String>class=ele.classNames(); //gives you the classnames of element containing Hello world
```

You can explore the library further to fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Using Java java.util.regex

```
String s = "<body>...<div class=\"abc\">Hello World</div></body>";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<div.+?class\\s*?=\\s*['\"]?([^ '\"]+).*?>Hello World</div>", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

prints abc

Comment: Is the HTML really going to be that constant?  If so, one would probably do as well just *looking at the source* and finding the info.  :P  If not, your regex will cause trouble.  `<div class="abc" id="broken">Hello World</div>` would match and capture "broken", for example.

Comment: [Right, parse HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: never try to parse html or xml using regex, check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: @OzHan in general I agree, but the question was about only finding "hello world" div class. Do you know a situation when regex cannot do that?

Comment: @EvgeniyDorofeev: Any situation where you can't guarantee the HTML will always be written a certain way, is going to give a regex hell.  Even something as simple as using single quotes instead of double, or not using quotes at all, would cause trouble.  Both are valid in HTML, but would break a naive regex.  And by the time you've built a regex capable of handling all the possible variations, you're at a point where simply using an existing, tested HTML parser would have saved you a lot of hair tearing.

Comment: Corrected my regex, now it's really hard to break

Answer (score 0):

Similiar question [Can jQuery get all CSS styles associated with an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/754607/can-jquery-get-all-css-styles-associated-with-an-element). Maybe css optimizers can do what you want, take a look at [unused-css.com](http://unused-css.com) its online tool but also lists other tools.

Answer (score 0):

As i understood you have chance to parse style sheet from external file and this makes your task easy to solve. First try to parse html file with [jsoup](http://www.jsoup.org) which supports jquery like selector syntax that helps you parse complicated html files easier. then check this [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513587/looking-for-a-css-parser-in-java) solution to parse css file. Im not going to full solution as i state with these libraries all task done internally and the only thing you should do is writing glue code to combine these two.