# Using java regex to find img tags without a width or height attribute

Tags: java, regex

What would be the regular expression for finding img tags without a width or height attribute? 
I have tried regex `<img(?!.*width).*?>` for width and `<img(?!.*height).*?>` for height .

Will it works without conflict and what is the combination of both regex ?

Comment: Ermm just put `|` (logical or) between them? Like: `<img(?!.*width).*?>|<img(?!.*height).*?>`. Not to mention you shouldn't parse HTML with regex.

Comment: Obligatory [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1702990)

Comment: Is any css parser available in java ?

Comment: yes, there are quite a good number of css parsers. You may want to check out this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513587/looking-for-a-css-parser-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution

Since you are using Java, here is a simple example for matching img tags without a width or height attribute. I used the [Jsoup html parser](http://jsoup.org):

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(myHtmlCode).get();
Elements imgsWithoutHeighOrWidth = doc.select("img:not(img[height], img[width])");
```

#### Demo

http://try.jsoup.org/~z1zP_fkmQPOi4Nbj87omMgbDbr0

#### Explanation

The big part here is the `cssQuery` passed to the `select` method.

I asked it to find:

```
img               => any img tags
   :not(          => not in 
      img[height] =>   any img tags with an `height` tag
      ,           =>   or
      img[width]  =>   any img tags with a `width` tag
   )
```

Comment: Thank Alex for your response , Is there a way to retrieve <img> tag **start line & column number and end line & column number** ? Because i need to highlight <img> tag (without width/height) in my own html editor .

Comment: @user2998596 I don't jnow how to do that. However, you can use the `.html()` method of an `Element` for getting the position of this element inside `myHtmlCode`. Checl Jsoup javaodc for more help: http://jsoup.org/apidocs/