# How to parse css file in Java

Tags: java, css, parsing

I want to parse css file using java code.
e.g. as below.
particular class and inside that different images. And I want to change background dynamically. Can someone provide give me example for same. Thanks.

```
classname {

background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #666666, #666666);

}
```

Comment: Why don't you google it? first attempt - [CSS Parser](http://cssparser.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513587/looking-for-a-css-parser-in-java

Answer (score 2):

Ehm,
You should really google before asking questions like this.
However, I did the work for you and found a number of libraries:

https://github.com/radkovo/jStyleParser

https://github.com/phax/ph-css

(Have not tested any of them just using them as example)

**Conclusion**: There is no "standard" way to parse css, you have to do it yourself or use a library.