# Is there a way to get with JavaFX the RGB value from CSS?

Tags: java, css, javafx

I have some color costants defined in my css file. I'd like to get this values in my code (They were not used so far). Is there a way to do that?

```
-color1: rgb(58, 135, 173);
-color2: rgb(70, 136, 71);
```

Comment: Can you show the related portion of css / provide some clarification on what you need?

Comment: @Peter of course, I'd like to get those values, is it possible? Actually I'm using the Color.rgb() function directly in my java code, but I don't like this solution

Comment: Is the reason you don't like the Color.rgb() solution because you have to set it against the controls, or that you're not sure how to apply the constants in your css file?

Comment: @Peter I don't like this solution, because I have to set the rgb color two times, in the css and in the control. The constants work well in the css. I looked for a while in the web, but seems there aren't API so far that can help you to get directly the css value

Comment: @Peter I'm not talking just about the RGB values. You can get the css class if it's already applied to some Node, but if you want to read some css values, I guess it's impossible

Comment: Maybe this post can give you some ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513587/looking-for-a-css-parser-in-java

Comment: @Peter Exactly as I thought, to use a CSS Parser is the only way possible. Thanks.