# css parser with Java and export it in a table

Tags: javascript, java, css, css-parsing

I need a parse for CSS.

For example:

```
.sapUiArea {

    background-color: #fafafa;

    color: #333333;

    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;

    font-size: 16px;
}
```

I need the name and color and generate with this information a table.

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513587/looking-for-a-css-parser-in-java

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Looking for a CSS Parser in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513587/looking-for-a-css-parser-in-java)

Comment: CSS file is in Root folder but it wont read the file so log file says Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
oParser.Parse("library.css") value is libary.css